# Android - FileNotFoundException while invoking openFileDescriptor on Uri returned from ContentResolver.insert()

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I've followed an example from Android's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item). My goal is to create a new file whose descriptor I will then pass to `MediaRecorder` in `setOutputFile`. I have the following code snippet:

```java
        ...

        ContentResolver resolver = getApplicationContext()
                .getContentResolver();

        Uri videoCollection;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            videoCollection = MediaStore.Video.Media
                    .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        } else {
            videoCollection = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }

        ContentValues videoDetails = new ContentValues();
        videoDetails.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                "video.mp4");

        Uri newVideoUri = resolver
                .insert(videoCollection, videoDetails);

        ParcelFileDescriptor file;

        try {
            file = resolver.openFileDescriptor(newVideoUri, "w");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     
        ...
```

To my surprise even though the resolver.insert() returns a Uri, when trying to open the fileDescriptor, a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown with a message:
`No such file or directory`.
The device I'm running this on has API version 23. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you open an InputStream for it?

Comment: No, it gives the exact same exception.

Comment: Sorry, i meant output stream (as there is no file yet for input).

Comment: Did you obtain write permission?

Comment: `insert(videoCollection, videoDetails);` Your linked document suggests `insert(videoCollection, videoDetails, null);`

Comment: I did make sure the 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` is granted, I'll try `OutputStream` tonight when I get home but I'm 99% sure I've tried already and it failed.

Comment: You did not mention runtime permission asked.

Comment: I do check the permissions in the Activity from which the above code is. Also, OutputStream also gives FileNotFoundException :(

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: The version is 6.0.1